# The selected certificate is not valid for coded signing

Tags: powershell, certificate, clickonce

I have the following Powershell script to create a new cert for a C# application:

```
$expirationDate = [datetime]::Today.AddYears(5)
$thumb = (New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\localmachine\my -DnsName $env:USERDNSDOMAIN -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -NotAfter $expirationDate).Thumbprint
$pwd = '123456'
$SSpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -Force -AsPlainText
$destinationDirectory = "C:\Test\" 
$filename = "mycert.pfx"
$pathAndFilename = $destinationDirectory + $filename
Export-PfxCertificate -cert "cert:\localmachine\my\$thumb" -FilePath $pathAndFilename -Password $SSpwd
```

It runs fine. Then in Visual Studio, in the application, on the project properties page, Signing tab, I click "Select from File" and browse to the file and I get:

> The selected certificate is not valid for coded signing. Choose
>   another certicate file.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot of Signing tab showing an existing cert]

Adding info based on @ConnorLSW comment. I have this script now:

```
$pwd = '123456'
$SSpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -Force -AsPlainText
$destinationDirectory = "C:\Test\" 
$filename = "mycert.pfx"
$pathAndFilename = $destinationDirectory + $filename
Import-PfxCertificate -cert "cert:\localmachine\my" -FilePath $pathAndFilename -Password $SSpwd
```

which outputs:

> Directory: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\my
>   Thumbprint                                                          Subject
>   AA1032E160156EC22D4447967A8B6401FF25E838  CN=AAAA.BBBB.CC.DDD

No mention of usage there and in the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/pkiclient/import-pfxcertificate) I see no mention of usage. How do I get this info?

Comment: if you import that certificate does it have code signing listed under its usages?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "import that certificate" .. how do you mean? I've added a screenshot of the Signing tab in Visual Studio to show how I'm getting to the pfx file.

Comment: Oh, i think you mean to use `Import-PfxCertificate` ... hold on...

Comment: @ConnorLSW: Please see updated info.

Comment: @AlLelopath , it's an old post, I know, but I must thank you for this PS sample. I've been struggling to create a usable self-signed cert for ClickOnce and this was the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run `New-SelfSignedCertificate` with `-Type CodeSigningCert` to get a certificate that's usable for code signing.

Yes, the `Get-Help` page for `New-SelfSignedCertificate` is super useless.

[Note that I cannot see your screenshot as that image host is blocked on my network.]

Comment: Sorry you can't see the screenshot (your employer is blocking Imgur?!) ... anyway, it turns out to be not too important giving that your answer is correct.

Comment: @AlLelopath Yep, I work for a K12 school district and imgur.com allows pornographic material.

Comment: oic, well that's probably for the best.