# Azure web app "Couldn't find a valid certificate"

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

So I created an ASP.NET Core website with IdentityServer authentication and published it to my Azure Web App but it complains about the certificate. I'm just using the default basic 1 tier web app with no custom domain. The web app is signed by a certificate out of the box so can't I just use that somehow?

Do I really need to buy a custom domain and my own certificate for this to work? I would prefer if I can just keep using the web app without a custom domain.

In the diagnostics dump I can see the error

```
   Couldn't find a valid certificate with subject 'CN=MyApplication' on the 'CurrentUser\My'
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.SigningKeysLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(String subject, String storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, DateTimeOffset currentTime)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.LoadKey()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.Configure(ApiAuthorizationOptions options)
```

**Startup.cs**

```
        var identityserver = services.AddIdentityServer();
        identityserver.AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, AutheticationDbContext>();
        identityserver.AddSigningCredentials();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

**appSettings.json**

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "MyWebProjectName.Client": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    },
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Store",
      "StoreName": "My",
      "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
      "Name": "CN=MyApplication"
    }
  }
```

Comment: "The web app is signed by a certificate out of the box so can't I just use that somehow?" -> No, because for App Services the SSL termination happens before the request even hits your app

Comment: My answer should be useful to you. It is feasible to use the default domain name of the webapp and create a self signed certificate. If you have any questions, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy your webapp, you will get a url like: `https://appname.azurewebsites.net`.

> Do I really need to buy a custom domain and my own certificate for this to work?

Then you can use powershell to generate [`self signed certificate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763022/new-selfsignedcertificate-certstorelocation-cannot-find-path). So you don't need to create a new domain or buy certificate.

After deployed app, you also need to upload your self signed certificate on portal, like Syarif Mathis's answer on below post.

[How to configure key settings for IdentityServer in appsettings.json for aspnet core app running on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246219/how-to-configure-key-settings-for-identityserver-in-appsettings-json-for-aspnet)